# MySQL Receiving Critical Errors

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Here is what I was trying to do:

```
CREATE TABLE first_filter (
  quote_datetime DATETIME,
  expiration     DATETIME,
  strike         FLOAT,
  option_type    VARCHAR(50),
  bid            FLOAT,
  ask            FLOAT,
  underlying_ask FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO first_filter
  SELECT *
  FROM   optionsdata
  WHERE  TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, quote_datetime, expiration) < 7 
     AND strike > 250 
     AND strike < 290 
     AND underlying_ask - strike < 16 
     AND underlying_ask - strike > -16
;
```

The end results of the `WHERE` statement is about 4 million rows and I am sure that all of the columns correspond correctly.

The error I received was this:

> Error Code: 1206. The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size

I tried to increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 10M, 150M, and 250M with no luck. Then at 300M I think I broke the configuration.

I cannot start the server now with these errors:

FROM W239.err:

```
2018-03-11T05:00:43  0  Warning  option 'read_buffer_size': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 8192
2018-03-11T05:00:43  0  Warning  option 'read_rnd_buffer_size': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 1
2018-03-11T05:00:43  0  Warning  TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-03-11T05:00:43  0  Warning  'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2018-03-11T05:00:43  0  Note  C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.21-log) starting as process 12868 ..
2018-03-11T05:00:43  0  ERROR  C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: option '--innodb-buffer-pool-dump-now' requires an argument
2018-03-11T05:00:43  0  ERROR  Parsing options for plugin 'InnoDB' failed.
2018-03-11T05:00:43  0  ERROR  Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2018-03-11T05:00:43  0  ERROR  Aborting
2018-03-11T05:00:43  0  Note  Binlog end
2018-03-11T05:00:43  0  Note  Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2018-03-11T05:00:43  0  Note  C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
```

5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete

```
2018-03-11 00:00:49 - Checking server status...
2018-03-11 00:00:49 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2018-03-11 00:00:49 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) (2003)
2018-03-11 00:00:49 - Assuming server is not running
```

All help is appreciated, I'm pretty much lost at this point. Thanks.

Comment: You did not only change `innodb_buffer_pool_size` (which is the correct way to solve your problem), but also added `innodb-buffer-pool-dump-now` without an argument, which is why the server won't start. Remove or fix it.

Comment: @bent. Is your MySQL running again, or do you still need assistance?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions for your my.cnf-ini [mysqld] section

```
#read_buffer_size=0  # lead with # or REMOVE for DEFAULT RAM needed
#read_rnd_buffer_size=0  # lead with # or REMOVE for DEFAULT RAM needed
```

is just step ONE.

Post newer error log after shutdown/restart so we can see your newest error messages, please.